# receiving transforms from openni_tracker

Tags: ros, transforms, openi-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The openni_tracker uses a TransformBroadcaster to publish the transforms it makes while tracking. I was going to write a subscriber node, but I realized that there is probably already one if openni_tracker is publishing something. Does anyone know the name of the subscriber node if it exists?

To clarify, I am looking for a specific node that uses a TransformListener to get information from the openni_tracker node.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10559/receiving-transforms-from-openni_tracker/) by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2011-07-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-07-11**:
Thanks for the help.

**Comment by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) on 2011-07-11**:
I'm afraid what you ask for is too specific for it to be available off-the-shelf. I'd insist on taking the TransformListener example and working from there. You can try to first receive just one of the transforms (e.g. right_hand) to get more confident and then extending to the rest of the frames.

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-07-11**:
I already looked at this tutorial, and had the same plan. However, it is somewhat confusing for me to create a node based on a very different one. If there's a node that already listens to openni_tracker, it'd be easier for me to make the connections between what I am doing and the existing node.

**Comment by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) on 2011-07-11**:
You should take the sample in http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29 and replace the frames that are requested to the TransformListener for any of the frames published by the openni_tracker. That should serve as a starting point to develop what you need.

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-07-11**:
constant?

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-07-11**:
I'm looking for any node that listens to openni_tracker. I don't need anything very complex, so any nodes will probably be sufficient. I just don't want to write a node if there's already an existing one, as I'm still not great with ROS. Also, why would the number of published transforms ever be

**Comment by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) on 2011-07-11**:
You're looking for a node that listens to information from openni_tracker and does what? A blank node that listens to transforms between "openni_depth_frame" and each of the frames published by openni_tracker? Bear in mind that the number of published transforms is not even constant.

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-07-11**:
Yes. Hopefully my update to the question makes it a bit more clear.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-07-11**:
Are you looking for a TransformListener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answered in comments by @Miguel Prada

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0